# How to send value to datagridview by button?

Tags: c#

How to send a button value to data grid view, if the data grid view cell is last focus then the button value goes to last focus cell.

```
void textBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
  lastFocused = (TextBox)sender; 
} 

private void btnone_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
  if (lastFocused != null) { lastFocused.Text += "1"; 
}
```

Just like passing value to textbox lastfocus from button click, I want to pass a value to datagridview lastfocused cell

Comment: its not possible to understand what you are trying to do,you could atleast show some code

Comment: This sounds like an implementation issue... You should consider your options with what you are wanting to do, using as Button for this is wrong.
I'd suggest editing your query, explaining what you are trying to do, this way we could possibly suggest a better way to achieve the result.

Comment: @YvesLarock You need to edit your original question with the code and a description of what you trying, i'd suggest you delete the comment and add it to the main question - there is an 'Edit" hyperlink you can click on.

Comment: You can do pretty much the same as you did by coding the datagridview.CellEnter event.. Also: always try to avoid scrollbars in code!

Comment: @YvesLarock You would need to figure out how to get the last cell of the datagridView and set the .text of it to the Button text. Research a little and give it a try. I still dont understand why you would want to do it this way... Doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you variable `lastFocused` is an `object` :

```
object lastfocused = null;
```

You can set it in the `CellEnter` event of the DGV.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    lastFocused = dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
}
```

Note that is can't be `Control` anymore as [`DataGridViewCell`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is not a `Control` but a `DataGridViewElement` which derives directly from `object`. And as it doesn't have a `Text` property we always need to cast now:..

In your `Button_Click` you can test for various cases:

```
if (lastFocused != null)
{
     if (lastFocused is DataGridViewCell) {
        ((DataGridViewCell)lastFocused ).Value += "1";
     }
     elseif (lastFocused is TextBox) { 
        ((TextBox)lastFocused ).Text += "1"; 
     }
}
 }
```

Btw: As `Buttons` don't really have 'values' many folks probably found the question to be so confusing they downvoted it.. Always try to be clear and explain not only the current problem but also the things you ultimately want to achieve with your code!

Comment: and how to user backspace key in datagridview last focus. just like back space in textbox
` int i = lastFocused.Text.Length;  lastFocused.Text = lastFocused.Text.Substring(0, i - 1);`

Comment: Yes, pretty much the same : `if (lastFocused is DataGridViewCell)
         {string s = ((DataGridViewCell)lastFocused).Value.ToString();
                ((DataGridViewCell)lastFocused).Value = s.Substring(0, s.Length-1);   }`